# Find the minimal value in stack with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, stack, min

I need to find the minimal value recursively in a stack and then return the min value...
I tried solve it iteratively and it's worked.

My try with recursion:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int minimalValue(Stack<Integer> s, int min) {
        if (s.isEmpty())
            return min;
        // Save the previous value.
        int prev = s.pop();

        if (!s.isEmpty() && prev < min)
            min = prev;
        return minimalValue(s, min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.push(99);
        stack.push(64);
        stack.push(73);
        stack.push(54);
        stack.push(100);
        stack.push(82);
        stack.push(55);
        stack.push(300);
        System.out.println(minimalValue(stack, stack.top()));

        in.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, every element in the stack was deleted after the method done.
Can you bring me a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain the original `Stack` as follows:

```
 public static int minimalValue(Stack<Integer> s) {
    if (s.isEmpty())
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int last = s.pop();
    int min = Math.min(last, minimalValue(s));
    s.push(last);
    return min;
}
```

This recursion was created by observing the the minimal value in the `Stack` is the minimum between the top of the `Stack` and the minimum of the `Stack` resulting by removing the top of the `Stack`.

By adding the popped element after each recursive call, I make sure that the `Stack` returns to its original state in the end.

Note that this solution doesn't require passing a second argument to the recursive method.

Testing:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(99);
stack.push(64);
stack.push(73);
stack.push(54);
stack.push(100);
stack.push(82);
stack.push(55);
stack.push(300);
System.out.println(minimalValue(stack));
System.out.println (stack);
```

Output:

```
54
[99, 64, 73, 54, 100, 82, 55, 300]
```

As you can see, in the end the `Stack` contains all of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably considered cheating, but you can avoid modifying the original stack by cloning it and operating on the clone.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Stack;

class Scratch {
    public static Optional<Integer> minimalValue(Stack<Integer> s, Optional<Integer> min) {
        if (s.empty()) {
            return min;
        }

        Integer topElement = s.pop();
        Integer newMin = Math.min(topElement, min.orElse(topElement));
        return minimalValue(s, Optional.of(newMin));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(99);
        stack.push(64);
        stack.push(73);
        stack.push(54);
        stack.push(100);
        stack.push(82);
        stack.push(55);
        stack.push(300);

        Stack<Integer> clone = (Stack) stack.clone();
        Optional<Integer> result = minimalValue(clone, Optional.empty());
        System.out.println(result.orElse(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! just the section that save the stack elements is missing. thx (:

Comment: @S.O.M I missed that requirement. I've posted an updated solution